# Group messages in android

Tags: android

Hi all I am working on an application in which i want group text messages from my android device. I do google but not find any sufficient help is there any way to get group text from database?

Comment: Do you want to create your own group chat application or do you want to integrate with existing chat application?

Comment: i don’t want to create new group chat app. i only want to retrieve group chat sms for my app

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be a unique id for each group for a group chat the chat content will be posted along with this groupid to the database and when we open and access a group chat page we can access based on this unique id.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. Can you please refer any working or example code or any kind of other reference that helps me sort this out. Thanks

Comment: @user2423768 Sorry I worked this out for an R&d process in my previous firm so I have no working code but can help you if you face any issue verifying your code.In parse.com they use this scenario which is suitable for our own way of coding also.